# Apostrophe/Accute accent breaking scripts

Tags: terminal, docker, language, special-characters

I'm pulling a large collection of pdf files from a server and some of them contain this character ’. On mac this is no problem and everything works fine, but when i run it on a linux environment it fails. If i try and paste the character in on it's own nothing happens, and if i paste it within a word and try and remove the previous character it turns into a ? mark.

[image]
[image]

Is there any solution that doesn't involve changing the filenames on the server?

Comment: What terminal do you use? What shell? What's your `locale` setting?

Comment: Terminal app on mac, linux running Ubuntu 20.04 inside docker container. /bin/bash. en_GB.UTF-8

Comment: I tried this on Windows with WSL and Docker. This appears to be something with Docker + Ubuntu + Bash. The Unicode apostrophe works fine with `echo` in my WSL Ubuntu, and also worked fine in Docker with Alpine Linux. But when I ran `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:20.04 bash` I got weird behavior pasting the Unicode apostrophe and got `Hamlet\342\200\231s` when pasting the word. 

Comment: If I have time, I'll check a little more, but this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637292/cannot-type-unicode-in-a-ubuntu14-04-container-can-type-just-fine-in-busybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it relates to the locale setting for the Ubuntu container you're running.

Stack Overflow has an answer that looks like it will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27102762/895323

Even on Windows, the following prevented me from using Unicode characters: `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:20.04 bash`.

By specifying the `LANG` environment variable as per the SO answer, Unicode worked.

```
docker run -e LANG=C.UTF-8 -it --rm ubuntu:20.04 bash
```